# Using JSON stringify result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string `[[[[244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]]]]`
What I am looking for is `[[244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]]`
and sometimes it has null values, I want to remove all null too.

```
var rectangle   =   [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        var backgroundxy  =   [finalBgCoord];
        var foregroundxy  =   [finalFgCoord];
        // console.log(foregroundxy)
        // console.log(backgroundxy)
        // console.log(rectangle)
        var jsfg    =  JSON.stringify(foregroundxy)
        var jsbg    =  JSON.stringify(backgroundxy)
        console.log(jsfg)
        console.log("test")
        console.log(foregroundxy)
```

[this is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rieCj.png)

Comment: Can't you just do `[[[[244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]]]][0]`?

Comment: Try to use `flat` method of array. `[[[[244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]]]].flat(2)[0]` You can pass a depth as argument to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two separate questions here.

First off, you say you have this:

```
[
  [
    [
      [244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]
    ]
  ]
]
```

...and want this:

```
[
  [244, 83, 245, 84], [276, 28, 275, 27]
]
```

That starting array has one item, so use `[0]` to access it. That first child also only has one item, so use `[0]` again to access that. That will give you the grandchild you're looking for:

```js
const rectArray = data[0][0];
```

Next, you're asking how to remove null values. You aren't clear on *where* these null values are in your question, but you can use the `.filter()` method of an array to only keep values matching a criteria. For example:

```js
const withoutNulls = rectArray.filter(rect => rect !== null);
```